# Cannot log in into the main account after installing Tex Live

Tags: 14.04

I installed Tex Live in my system. The program suggested that I have a low space and So I removed some files to make space for it. After that I had to force shutdown for nothing was working. Then when I restarted again I am unable to log in into my main account. I can although log in into the guest account.

What should I do now??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you login to tty1 (press ctrl+alt+f1 to go to tty1)?

Comment: @wb9688 Ye s I can. What should I do after getting into tty1??

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? (Lubuntu 15.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Kubuntu 14.10, etc.) Are you connected to internet?

Comment: 14.04.. yes connected to the internet

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: from where?? I cannot log in

Comment: Can't you login to tty1 with your username and password? Have you changed the password of the `root` user?

Comment: I entered the command. It is asking me for passowrd I guess

Comment: But after entering the password I cannot log in.

Comment: Yeah, it's asking for your user's password. After `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, can you change the root password with `sudo passwd root` and try to log in as root in the desktop manager?

Comment: Which files do you have removed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27425/discussion-between-tattwamasi-amrutam-and-wb9688).